# 'allow_concurrent_memtable_write' on a column family level

Tags: leveldb, rocksdb

RocksDB supports concurrent writes on a memtable via the option, `allow_concurrent_memtable_write` which is a part of `RocksDB Immutable DBOptions`. Since this is a DBOption, this setting is applicable to all CFs created in the DB. 
 But I have a requirement where i want to enable concurrent writes in certain CFs and disable in others. Treating it more like a `ColumnFamilyOptions`.

I understand that, I can have two database pointers and separate the column families based on concurrent_writes setting. Still I would like to know if it can be done within the same DB.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible, its a DB Level option not a column family option.